# Removing consecutive characters from permutation

Tags: python, permutation

I have a pretty simple permutations script to write the permutations to a file and a timer to say how long the script takes to complete.

```
from itertools import permutations  
import time
start_time = time.time()
str = '012345'

file=open("p1.txt","a")
perm = permutations(str, 6)  
    
for i in perm:  
    file.write(''.join(i))
    file.write('\n')
else:
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
file.close()
```

It gives me all the permutations of 012345. What I'd like to try and achieve is to remove consecutive characters, both before an after.

For example, if the permutation is 05314, that would be OK. Non of characters are consecutive, either forwards or backwards. But if the permutation is (a) 05324 or (b) 05231, neither of these should work because in (a) 2 follows 3 backwards, and in (b) 3 follows 2 forwards.

Is something like this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Do you wish to (1) remove consecutive characters, or (2) remove the entire string if consecutive characters are found? IOW, what should be the output for the violators you mention?

Comment: So if `052341` is encountered then does removing `3` satisfy your request or do you expect `34` to be removed? If `34` is to be removed then you are left with `0521` so does it need to be re-processed?

Comment: Does your code work?  You have `str = '012345'` which masks the builtin function.  But, later you try to use the builtin function with `file.write(str(i))`.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new on here, not sure if I can quote individual comments....but anyway;

jpf / MonekyZeus - If consecutive characters occur, I'd ideally like to remove that line from the output, rather than just removing the violating characters.

DarrylG - Good catch ... I'd remove the wrong line from my scribbles; I should have left in file.write(''.join(i)) ... I've edited the code above, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying code to filter out consecutive pairs in permutations

```
from itertools import permutations  
import time

start_time = time.time()
s = '012345'            # Don't use str = ... since its masks the builtin function

with open("p1.txt","a") as file:
    perm = permutations(s, 6)  

    for i in perm:  
        if not any(abs(ord(a)-ord(b))==1 for a, b in zip(i, i[1:])):
            # Does not have any consecutive pairs in i
            file.write(str(i))
            file.write('\n')
    else:
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

**Explanation**

*General idea*

- The pair of numbers (a, b) is consecutive increasing/decreasing if and only if (iff) abs(a-b) == 1.
- A list has at least one consecutive pair of increasing/decreasing iff there is a consecutive increasing/decreasing pair in the list.

*Application of Idea*

Given list lst, we can find all consecutive pairs using zip i.e. zip(lst, lst[1:])

So the consecutive pairs list is:

```
 [(a, b) for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
```

All consecutive pairs increasing/decreasing then is:

```
[(a, b) for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if abs(a-b)== 1]
```

All we care is if there is at least one pair in this list.  We can use any for this i.e.

```
any(abs(a-b) == 1 for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```

The above works for a list of numbers, but we have to make a slight adjustment for a list of digits.

```
any(abs(ord(a) - ord(b)) == 1 for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```

This works by checking if two string digits are one apart by checking if their Unicode decimal representations are one apart.  The Unicode decimal is provided by the ord function.  Note digits "0" to "9" has Unicode decimal 48 to 57 [List of Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

Comment: That looks like it works, thank you :-)

I'm going to look up "how" it works, because that functionality is new to me, but it appears to be doing exactly what I asked for!

Comment: @Darren--added an explanation.  Does this help?

Comment: Thank you, it's much appreciated and gives me a good base for working on a few other idea.

Comment: @Darren--Something you could try is backtracking.  Python permutations is fast since it's [implemented in c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c).  However, if you have constraints on the permutations I sometimes find Python code faster using backtracking when the constraints eliminate a large portion of the permutations.